# Slim\\Route::__invoke() with Middleware is not accepting the right $request & $response

Tags: php, slim, middleware

I am currently writing a REST API using Slim Framework 3 and implementing Middleware for basic authentication.

My routing goes like this:

```
$app->group('/api', function () use ($app, $pdo) {
    $this->group('/v1', function () use ($app, $pdo) {

        // Guest Routes
        $this->group('', function() use ($app, $pdo) {
            require_once '../app/api/v1/authentication.php';
        });

        // Authenticated Routes
        $this->group('', function() use ($app, $pdo) {
            require_once '../app/api/v1/test.php';
        })->add(new \App\Middleware\AuthMiddleware($pdo));

    });
});
```

In the AuthMiddleware class I am using the __invoke method in the following way:

```
namespace App\Middleware;

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class AuthMiddleware extends Middleware {

/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Response $response
 * @param $next
 * @return Response
 */
    public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, $next) {

        $response = $next($response, $request);

        return $response;
    }

}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to Slim\Route::__invoke() must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface, instance of Slim\Http\Response given

on the following line:

```
$response = $next($response, $request);
```

What is happening? any ideas? I've been eating myself over this for 2 hours :(

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It looks like you are mixing slim versions. The method signature for a route in version 3 is `$app->get('/path', function (Request $request, Response $response){...});` in a group you just use `$this` and do not need to `use(app)`.  Also in your setup of slim you could add the `pdo` var to the container and then access it like: `$this->pdo->methodName();`

Comment: Thanks @nerdlyist, but when I add the pdo to the container PHPStorm just stops auto-completion for pdo methods.

Comment: Hum... that seems odd for them to do maybe get some support but I would not suggest basing your system architecture off of that. It adds a lot of benefits to have that in the container over in the route for example if you want to move to controllers over a bloated index file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stupidly.. I noticed that on

```
$response = $next($response, $request);
```

I reversed the parameters.. should be

```
$response = $next($request, $response);
```

Blaahh... my head hurts.

Comment: I feel your pain!